# Why won't Entity insert with assigned ID?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, sqlite, linq-to-entities

So with the following Method:

```
        Vendor NewVendor = new Vendor();
        NewVendor.Name = "New Vendor Test";
        NewVendor.Active = true;
        NewVendor.ID = 999999;

        c.Vendors.Add(NewVendor);
        c.SaveChanges();
```

where vendors is:

```
[Table("Vendors")]
public class Vendor
{
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

why is it that when the new vendor is inserted into the database (SQLite) the VendorID is not used? instead the Id is being autoincremented.

the table is not set to autoincrement:

```
CREATE TABLE "Vendors" ("ID" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY  NOT NULL ,"Name" TEXT NOT NULL , "Active" BOOL DEFAULT 1)
```

and the following SQL command works as expected:

```
Insert Into Vendors
Values (999999, 'New Vendor Test', 1)
```

Comment: You should use a profiler and see what type of query arrives at your database when you trigger the `SaveChanges` method, and compare with your SQL query that performs as expected.

Comment: @AlexBarac How would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following solution

```
[Table("Vendors")]
public class Vendor
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's the opposite of what I want.

Comment: try to define ID as int.sometimes it create issue when datatype mismatch with database.

Comment: No change when setting to int instead

Comment: Modify Your answer, instead of `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` set it to `DatabaseGeneratedOption.None`, that is what worked.

Answer (score -1):

It is exactly *because* the field in the database is set to auto increment. The value provided will be overriden by the database.